# How do I find the steepest part of a curve I know the equation for?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been asked on my task to "Correctly find the maximum/minimum gradient for each ascent or descent calculated and shown to be less than tan(pi/4). Must be shown mathematically."

Am I right in saying that the steepest part of the curve should be the points of inflection?

Comment: It might be a horizontal point of inflection in which case, no.

Comment: Yes, the steepest part will be at points of inflection.  The steepness is measured by the derivative, and the steepness is maximized where the derivative of the derivative is zero.  However, just as the derivative can be zero at a place that isn't the maximum you do not know that a point of inflection will always have the maximum steepness, even locally.

Comment: How do I find the steepest points of my graph?

Comment: You can also have steepest slope at the end of your domain, or at discontinuities (either in the function or just in the derivative). Look for example at $|\sin x|$.